# Laravel max_prepared_stmt_count error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Suddenly, my Laravel application stopped working while I was trying to log in.

It seems that many connections are being opened, but not closed... and some limit is reached.

```
(2/2) QueryException
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1461 Can't create more than max_prepared_stmt_count statements (current value: 16382) (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = joaopaulofurtado@live.com limit 1)
```

Comment: Show us some code. Is the query in a loop?

Comment: Thats the strange thing. I didnt change NOTHING. It suddenly crashed my whole application...

Comment: If the query is in a loop it's entirely possible a changing dataset caused this. By the error it looks like you prepared a statement a whole lot of times (16382), which is the limit in your environment. I guess you can work around this temporarily by preparing the statement just once and executing it inside the loop.

Comment: Im not using raw php to develop my application. I'm using eloquent to database relationship, so, I dont know how this issue came out

Comment: There's no way we can help you if you don't post some relevant code. Please update your question.

Comment: Thank you, it suddenly started working again. Probably, its some issue related with my shared hosting (godaddy).

Comment: I didnt post anything since i didnt change nothing on my code. This error just appeared and disappeared now.

Comment: But thank you for your disponibility to help

Answer (score 2):

[max_prepared_stmt_count](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_prepared_stmt_count) setting limits the maximum number of prepared statements that can concurrently exist in mysql at **server level**. Every time you want to create a new prepared statement, mysql checks against this limit first and if the mysql server has too many prepared statements, then blocks the new ones with the error message you see.

You mentioned in comments that you are on shared hosting. If the customers of your hosting provider share the same mysql server, then all the prepared ststements created by the customers use the same pool of available prepared statements and the mysql instance has simply hit the limit.

The only thing you can do if this error persists is to change hosting providers or use your own server. Providers are unlikely to change the setting since it affects the overall mysql performance, but you can slso try to ask them if the limit can be increased or the offending application can be stopped.

Comment: Is there a way to clean up the number of prepared statements? We encountered this error when running feature tests in Laravel 6

Answer (score 0):

You must be running your code in a loop with a lot of datas;

Laravel QueryBuilder and EloquentBuilder useing **pdo prepared statments** to run query. Laravel don't drop the statement in one single session, If you are running your code in a loop, it will keep generating prepared statements in the memory until reaches the limit of **max_prepared_stmt_count** setting. I don't know how to drop the prepared statement, so I use native sql to avoid Laravel generating prepared statements, and it works.

```
$sql = '.......';
DB::getPdo()->exec($sql);    // for update
$results = DB::getPdo()->query($sql)->fetchAll();    // for select
```